# Windows shell command: copy command without a destination

Tags: cmd, copy

I've just encountered this line of Windows code:

`copy mydir`

Looking at `help copy` I see:

```
COPY [/D] [/V] [/N] [/Y | /-Y] [/Z] [/L] [/A | /B ] source [/A | /B]
     [+ source [/A | /B] [+ ...]] [destination [/A | /B]]

  source       Specifies the file or files to be copied.
  /A           Indicates an ASCII text file.
  /B           Indicates a binary file.
  /D           Allow the destination file to be created decrypted
  destination  Specifies the directory and/or filename for the new file(s).
  /V           Verifies that new files are written correctly.
  /N           Uses short filename, if available, when copying a file with a
               non-8dot3 name.
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /-Y          Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
  /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.
  /L           If the source is a symbolic link, copy the link to the target
               instead of the actual file the source link points to.

The switch /Y may be preset in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless COPY command is being executed from
within a batch script.

To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).
```

but I'm struggling to understand from the documentation what omitting the destination does.

Any suggestions?

Comment: by omitting the second parameter (destination), it copies to the current folder ("copy to here").

Comment: (third example on [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html))

Comment: ...maintaining the original source file name(s)...

Comment: Please remember that the destination will be the current working directory, _(not necessarily that in which the batch file resides)_. So if your code doesn't specifically stipulate that directory, usually via the `CD` or `PushD` commands, the command shouldn't really be omitting the destination.